# Need To split a string comma separated including round brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var data = "39,'2020-04-24','2020-04-24','(2,3,4,5)','(2,3,4)','(36,43,79)',-1,50000,0";
```

I want the string to be in the form of array-like

```
[39,"2020-04-24","2020-04-24","(2,3,4,5)","(2,3,4)","(36,43,79)", -1 , 50000 , 0 ];
```

Comment: ```const arr = data.split(',');``` what is problem with it?

Comment: Might be worth looking into ways to pass your `data` to `JSON.parse` if you wrap it with brackets like `JSON.parse(\`[${data}]\`)`?

Comment: @SajeebAhamed because it would break apart the items inside the () like the OP said.

Comment: But his expected output sees nothing.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed do the split and compare it to the expected output. You would clearly see why it would fail. `"(2", "3", "4", "5)"` does not match `"(2,3,4,5)"`

Comment: I get it. It's by bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some fun stuff with regular expressions, but easiest thing is to make it into a format that JSON.parse can handle. Ideally whatever is generating it would make it proper JSON, but if it can not be changed you can alter it to be like this.

```js
var data = "39,'2020-04-24','2020-04-24','(2,3,4,5)','(2,3,4)','(36,43,79)',-1,50000,0";
var result = JSON.parse('[' + data.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']')
console.log(result)
```

There are edge cases where this will fail, but if the data always looks like your example it will work.

The old school way before JSON.parse was with new Function (), but that has security concerns since it is evaling code.

```js
var data = "39,'2020-04-24','2020-04-24','(2,3,4,5)','(2,3,4)','(36,43,79)',-1,50000,0";
var result = (new Function('return [' + data + ']')())
console.log(result)
```

Comment: taking about my current scenario it works well thanx.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this `,(?=(?:[^\(\)]*\([^\(\)]*\))*[^\(\)]*$)`**

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Mwc8w/1)